# Should an object being created by a factory method accept constructor arguments?

Tags: php, constructor, factory-pattern

I'm currently using the factory pattern to create users but I'm having a problem with a constructor issue.

I have the following as my factory:

```
class userFactory {

public function factoryMethod(user $user_type) {

    $user = new $user_type($db);

    return $user;

}

}
```

I then instantiate the class as follows:

```
$user = new userFactory();
$user = $user->factoryMethod(new admin());
```

The issue is, I need to pass $db as a parameter into the new admin() call but I can't find a way of doing it or even if it's possible.

Have I overlooked something simple or is this simply not possible?

Comment: It can if you use reflection to instantiate the object - http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php - that's how I do it in my factories

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I'll go investigate.